# Selecting specific cell in sql

Tags: php, sql

This is for a login system. When I want the user to login I want it to take the given password and compare it to the column "Password" of the row that is given...In this case `$usernameinput` but the method I am using is not working. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

$usernameinput = $_POST["uname"];
$passwordinput = $_POST["pass"];

if (empty($usernameinput))
{
echo "";
}

else
{

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","STUFFFFF","STUFFFFFF");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

HERE IS WHERE IT SELECTS

```
mysql_select_db("STUFFFFF", $con);

$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE Username='$usernameinput'");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $matchpassword = $row['Password'];
  }
}
```

---

```
if (empty($passwordinput))
{
echo "";
}
else
{

if ("$passwordinput"=="$matchpassword")
{
$sqlusername = $usernameinput;
echo "You were logged in successfully, now you can visit the site as $sqlusername. <br />"; 
}
else
{
echo "You have entered an incorrect password.";
}

}
?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /> <br />
<input value="Login" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should be aware of sql injection: WHERE Username='$usernameinput'"

Comment: Get rid of extra quot here: "$passwordinput"=="$matchpassword"

Comment: In Stackoverflow there're tons of related question. Just search ;)

Comment: extra quote? And all the related searches I have been to did not select a specific column and row the same way :/

Comment: this "$passwordinput"=="$matchpassword" is totally equivalent to this $passwordinput==$matchpassword

Comment: oh ok I'll keep that in mind...still won't help my problem though lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']).'"';
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
if ($user['password'] == sha1($_POST['password'])) {
    //Logged in
} else {
    //Wrong password
}
```

That way you prevent MySQL injections and the passwords of your users are safe.

Comment: @SpencerMay: Of course, you'll need to replace the column names by yours, and probably save the passwords in sha1 format.. or simply drop that part of the check, it's up to you. (I updated the code)

Comment: If you are using PHPMyAdmin, you can insert a new entry, and chose SHA1 in the option right left to your password... or with PHP when doing an insert, do sha1() before.. or simply store them not hashed... it's weaker but hey, everybody needs to learn.

Comment: I do use PHPMyAdmin but I will eventually have people register on this site so how would sha1() work? Because im guessing I need that to make your above code work.

Comment: when you create an entry in the database at the registration, something like this:  `mysql_query('INSERT INTO users("username","password") VALUES("'.$_POST['username'].'", "'.sha1($_POST['password'].'")');`

Comment: The purpose of sha1() is to obfuscate the password in case someone hack your site. It's a hashing method, you cannot decrypt a sha1(). So instead, when the user registers, you hash is password and save it like that, and when he tries to connect, you do the same thing and compare the hash with the one in the database.

Comment: Im just working on getting your code to work it has a php error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14204/discussion-between-alex-belanger-and-spencer-may)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to query columns in resultset by name.

Comment: I tried this...still not working, I'm not even sure what ^ that function does lol

Comment: it's often helpful to run print_r($row) or var)_dump($data) on things you get back from the database to make sure you're working with what you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add your password parameter to your SQL statement.

WHERE username = '" . $usernameinput . "' and password = '" . $passwordinput . "'

Then test whether or not there are any results.

Also to note, you should always encrypt passwords in your database for security and privacy reasons. Look into that. In addition, you should use mysqli functions, not mysql ones due to their enhanced protection.

Sorry about the formatting, I'm using a phone =/

Off the top of my head it'd be like:

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($rows <1){
   //no username found, wrong pw
}
else{
   //username and pw match
}

Comment: That sounds like it would work, I will look into protecting it but first I need to get it to work lol. Would I put this into an if statement or what?

Comment: May I also add I am new to sql and have been pounding my head trying to figure it out. I have the register page done and all I have left is this.

Comment: @SpencerMay made it back to a computer.  Any luck?